# How to get the parent fieldgroup group_name for a field_collection_table?

Tags: 7, entities

My case is the following:

I have a custom node with some field collections and all of these are shown on a htab group, each one in it's own tab.

**Now, what I want/need to do is**: return to the page and focus on the htab group, opening the respective tab, after adding/editing any item on these collections.

**What I managed to so far**:

- I could do the return-to-node thing, changing a little the field_collection.module code, merely adding the "destination" parameter to the links.
- I *can* do the focus and select tab thing on whatever page, if I manually point it to the tab anchor for example.

The actual tab (it's outermost wrapper) is a fieldset with an id with the following pattern: #<entity_type>_<type_name>_<view_mode>_<group_name> (#node_mytype_full_groupxyz)

I already changed the links to use a hardcoded anchor and it works, but I'm trying now to do it dinamically, and that's where I'm stalled. In the field_colletion_table.module, the link is set in a hook implementation (field_collection_table_field_formatter_view), where I found most of what I needed:

```
$entity_type //'node'
$entity->type //'mytype'
$content['#view_mode'] //'full'
```

**What I need to know**: is there a way (query?) to get the group_name of the fieldgroup (tab) which contains the field_collection(_table)?

Comment: Hmm, just to have you think of a different approach.  I have added a field to the node to store the anchor tab of the htab.  I did this so I could use views to create blocks in other parts of the site and link directly to that tab.  I would auto save the anchor on node_save so the user doesn't have to enter it.  Just some food for thought to give you some extra flexibility.

Comment: @iLLin I like your idea, even if I call it a workaround, it probably is as clean as a "direct" solution can get. Implementing it, at least if/while I do not find what I asked, thanks!